# How to open “Paid” app page in iPhone's AppStore by clicking button in “Lite” app?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have 2 versions of an app. Lite and Paid. I want to have a button in Lite version which when clicked opens App Store application on iPhone and shows the page for Paid version of the app.

How do I do this? I DONT want to open Paid version iTunes page in Safari. It should open in App Store application only.

This is a bad solution. iPhone opens **Safari first, then AppStore**.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/YOUR APP ID NO."]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocol `itms-apps://` solves problem. **Only AppStore** opens.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/YOUR APP ID NO."]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/{yourCountryCode}/app/idXXXXXXXXX"]];
```

where XXXXXXXXX is your app id

i think it doesnt get better than this.

EDIT: This link also doesn't know more and is pretty good from what i know: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#App_Store